# Parsin JSON with @ sign in key field

Tags: c#, json

I am getting JSON as follow:

```
        "NAME": {
            "@value": "FOO"
        },
        "LASTNAME": {
            "@value": "BAR"
        },
        "BIRTH": {
            "@value": "198701010000"
        }
```

when i try to parse this, i am unable to get the values like 'Foo', 'Bar' and bday.

```
Rootobject deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(obj);
```

I m using the code above to parse it.

How can i parse this properly?

Comment: what is your `RootObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a class `RootObject` that looks like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Item Name { get; set; }

    public Item LastName { get; set; }

    public Item Birth { get; set; }
}
```

You can define `Item` like this:

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("@value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and use the `JsonProperty` attribute to specify the name of the property you'd like to map `Item.Value` to.